# login and register in One page using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

i'm trying to use login and register in one page in react tsx and this is my code but when i click to show login it's show for like 1 second and then return to signup i don't know why the state change

```
import React, { ReactElement, Fragment, useState } from 'react'

interface Props { }
function Home({ }: Props): ReactElement {
    const [login, setlogin] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="welcomdiv">
                <h1 id="weltxt">Welocme to your Todo List</h1>
                <h3 id="strtxt">Let's Start By Making a Account</h3>
            </div>
            {login ?
                <form className="form-signin">
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required />
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>
                :
                <form className="form-signup">
                    <input type="text" name="username" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" required />
                    <input type="email" name="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required />
                    <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                    <input type="password" name="password2" className="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
                    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </form>}
            <p id="logintxt">Alrady have an Account , Want to <a href="" onClick={() => setlogin(true)}>Login</a></p>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Try using `button` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because button with the `type`, `submit`, will actually try to trigger the form's default submit action.

```
<button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

If you do not wish that to happen, you can simply switch the `type` to `button`, and manually bind the `onClick` event to your custom click handler method.

```
type="button"
```

You may read more about the submit behaviour over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit).

In addition, it will be more specific if you type your functional component as `React.FC<Props>`, instead of `ReactElement`.